# How to get firefox to show an auto horizontal scollbar for a div?

Tags: css, firefox, scrollbar

See [this pastie](http://pastie.org/425172) in firefox. When resizing the browser window horizontally, then when the yellow area gets hidden a bit I want a horizontal scrollbar to appear. In Safari this code works fine. How would you style this for firefox?

*I am using overflow:auto; I only want the scrollbar to appear when it makes sense, I don't want to see it all the time*

Answer (score 2):

Firefox doesn't recognize `overflow-x` and `overflow-y`.

Instead use `overflow:-moz-scrollbars-horizontal;` or `overflow:-moz-scrollbars-vertical`;

This is a Mozilla Firefox specific hack so none of the other browsers should be affected.

Answer (score 0):

The best to use would be overflow: auto; this will add a scroll bar only when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Specify some width and then "overflow: scroll;"