# Firefox: How to prevent horizontal scrollbar with when min-width and max-height is used?

Tags: css, firefox, html, cross-browser, scrollbar

I have a dynamically created table placed in a div. Whole structure can be arbitrarily positioned on the page. Requirements are (automatic vertical scrollbar and never horizontal scrollbar):
 - minimal width which enlarges when the text is longer 
- maximum height and when there is more rows scrollbar should appear .
 
HTML:

```
<div class="container" style="top:5px;">
<table>
  <tr><td style="white-space: nowrap;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit;</tr></td>
  <tr><td>2ed do eiusmod tempor</tr></td>
  <tr><td>3ed do eiusmod tempor</tr></td>
  <tr><td>4ed do eiusmod tempor</tr></td> 
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
   background-color: grey;  
   max-height: 50px;min-width: 70px;
   overflow-y: auto;
   position: absolute;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PUMAj/

The code works as intended in IE (10) but there is a horizontal scrollbar in Firefox when a vertical scrollbar appears. It seems the width of scrollbar is not calculated correctly in Firefox. I tried  `overflow:-moz-scrollbars-vertical;`, which hides the horizontal scrollbar ([How to get firefox to show an auto horizontal scollbar for a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676388/how-to-get-firefox-to-show-an-auto-horizontal-scollbar-for-a-div)) but part of the text is hidden under scrollbar and `overflow-y:scroll;` which cause that vertical scrollbar is always present but does not hide the text.

**Edit**

The desired output is (IE10)

[image: IE10 result]

But in Firefox I have this:

[image: Firefox Result]

Proposed overflow hidden is not a solution.

[image: overflow-y hidden] `overflow-y:hidden`(desired scrolling not possible)

[image: overflow x hiden] `overflow-x:hiden` (part of the text is hidden)

Comment: overflow-y: hidden; ?

Comment: Or maybe `overflow: auto`. It will only show the scrollbars once the contents exceed the dimensions of the container.

Comment: @davidb I need to have y scrollbar when then necessary, but showing it shows in firefox an x scrollbar (due to wrong sizing?).

Comment: This bug is still present in Firefox 80. (2021)

Answer (score 1):

Just add some padding at the right :)

```
padding-right: 8px;
overflow-x: hidden;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PUMAj/18/

[image: without padding]
[image: with padding]